# Need help in showing $T_f$ = $\{A \subset X : A = \varnothing $ or $X - A$ is finite $\} $ is closed under union of arbitrary elements of $T_f$.

Tags: general-topology

If {$U_\alpha$} is an indexed family of non-empty elements of $T_f$ ,i'm not getting  *how $X- \bigcup U\alpha$ =$\bigcap (X-U\ \alpha)$ is a finite set?*

Comment: The intersection is contained in any of the $X-U_{\alpha}$, all of which are finite.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood:Means cardinality of index family {$U_ \alpha$} is finite?

Comment: The indexed family need not be finite.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood:I got it,actually I misunderstood your  comment.Thanks for help!